# How to set React Table selected rows from parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table, react-table-v7

I have a React Table component with selectable rows. Row selection works fine and the parent component has information about the selected rows as well. However, I would also want to be able to set the selected rows from the parent component. I have a Codesandbox example of the situation. Here, the "Empty selection" button doesn't work as I would want it to work. It affects only the state of the parent component, but not the React Table selected rows.

https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-react-table-doesnt-work-gy13z?file=/src/App.js

The code snippet is modified based on this example:
[https://spectrum.chat/react-table/general/v7-how-get-selected-rows-outside-of-react-table~2deb9558-c484-4b97-9e1c-6be608f1f275](https://spectrum.chat/react-table/general/v7-how-get-selected-rows-outside-of-react-table%7E2deb9558-c484-4b97-9e1c-6be608f1f275)

Other options that I have considered include using the useControlledState hook, but then the parent component state kind of always overrides the React Table's own state and selecting rows with clicking doesn't work anymore. However, it probably would be possible to build some kind of a working solution with this approach and it seems to be the way that React Table documentation recommends for controlling the state.

I could also reset the selected rows with autoResetSelectedRows, but then they would be reset even when I wouldn't want them to.

Answer (score -1):

We ended up solving this by using the React ref feature. This discussion includes an example of using them in a similar case:

https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/issues/3142